# Problems with capture cis simulation

Tags: simulation, pspice

I am trying to run some simulations on capture(PSPICE) for a school assignment and then compare the results of them with the results that i got when trying these circuits in the lab. However the results are completely different and i can't find any mistake in the circuit. The circuit is this:
[image] 
What's supposed to happen is to get a sine waveform of 4V pp on the collector of the transistor with a phase difference of 180 degrees from the original for a certain value of the {r} resitor.The resistor gets its values through a parametric sweep starting at 10k, ending at 300k and with an increment of 10k(the value of the resistor for which i got the output that i wanted was 111kΩ ).All i'm getting though is this waveform:
[image] 
which is clearly a distorted signal and with a pp voltage bigger than expected.
Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help.

Comment: Which transistor model are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you simulated it, but to me, this is a normal expected result when applying a 40mVp sine to a 0.7V Vbe self-biased voltage with an exponential Ic vs Vbe.  So your transistor Vce is entering saturation (Vce<0.3V) and gets a flat negative peak and reduced voltage gain in the other direction.

[Two of  many ways to fix this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%2012%206.250000000000001e-8%203.3115451958692312%201%20120%2068%0Av%20128%20192%20128%2080%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20128%2080%20288%2080%202%0Ag%20128%20192%20128%20208%200%0AR%20208%20176%20208%20208%200%201%2010000%200.04%200%200%200.12%0At%20240%20144%20288%20144%200%201%20-2.5102307410994125%200.6164011229934057%20100%0Ag%20288%20176%20288%20192%200%0Ac%20208%20144%20240%20144%200%200.0000010000000000000002%20-0.6876244270641495%0Ar%20240%20128%20288%20128%200%2062380%0Ar%20288%20128%20288%2080%200%204700%0Ar%20384%20160%20384%20128%200%204700%0Ar%20432%20160%20432%20128%200%204700%0Ac%20336%20128%20384%20128%200%204.7000000000000004e-8%202.5724477961265695%0Ac%20384%20128%20432%20128%200%204.7000000000000004e-8%200.1126980062649624%0Aw%20288%20176%20384%20160%200%0Aw%20384%20160%20432%20160%200%0Aw%20288%20128%20336%20128%200%0Aw%20240%20128%20240%20144%200%0Ar%20288%20160%20288%20176%200%2025%0Ar%20208%20144%20208%20176%200%2050%0Ao%2010%208%200%2020746%202.5%200.1%200%202%2010%203%20Output%0Ao%2015%208%200%2012546%203.97311078106522%200.0001%200%202%2015%203%20Collector%0Ao%2016%208%200%2012546%200.7251764137004348%200.0001%200%202%2016%203%20Base%0A38%207%200%201000%20100000%20Feedback%5CsResistance%0A) :

1. Reduce input from 40mVp to between 1%~2% of Vbe to 7 mV, with expected lower output.
2. add an emitter resistor to linearize the input impedance such that  Rc/Re< 2*hFE to reduce the exponential effects

   - Re=25 Ohms will work, then the input can be increased up to 100mVp
   - voltage gain must be less than half of  Rc/Re since you have a HPF with the same load R values as Rc.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll try the solutions and see how it goes.